# Loop a list of typedefs

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming, typedef

I'm sorry if the title is a bit misleading.

I have a function that loops some data. The type of this data change for every iteration.

Basically i have something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
  type object;
  object.do_stuff();
}
```

Here for example in the first iteration "type" will be int, on the second iteration "type" will be double, etc.

I can't use varyadic templates because i have more than 100 elements and from what i know it will be very taxing for the system.

My idea was to create a "vector of typedefs" to cycle all the types of the objects.

```
vector<????> type;
type.push_back(int);
type.push_back(double);
...
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
  type[i] object;
  object.do_stuff();
}
```

I don't know if this is even remotely possible.

I saw the basics of the typelists, but i don't know if it's possible to reproduce the loop.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::tuple` ?

Comment: `int::do_stuff` would be invalid BTW.

Comment: Did you actually try variadic templates? *"from what i know it will be very taxing for the system"* It could take longer to compile, but there should be no runtime overhead.

Comment: with your logic a program should never contain 100 vectors with different types. That seems very unresonable

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't knew about the tuples! Sure looks like tuple is what i'm looking for, thank you! And yes, about int::do_stuff it was my error in writing the example, should be int a; a::do_stuff.

HolyBlackCat & Default I've tried, but my manager told me that if i surpass 20 types in a varyadic template the system will be slowed down too much. It's important that the compile time is little as possible.

Comment: The contents of `do_stuff` may show another possible approach.

Comment: @doctorlove unfortunately i can't tell what the content is, but now is empty so it's really the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can't use varyadic templates because i have more than 100 elements and from what i know it will be very taxing for the system.

What you know is either outdated or inaccurate. Just look at [metaben.ch](http://metaben.ch/#) to get an idea of how big typelists can get with minimal compile time impact.

---

> My idea was to create a "vector of typedefs" to cycle all the types of the objects.

That's a typelist. Here's what you can do:

```
// Store the type in a value for convenience
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct typelist
{
    template <typename F>
    constexpr void for_each(F&& f)
    {
        // C++17 fold expression over comma operator
        (f(type_wrapper<Ts>{}), ...);
    }
};
```

---

C++17 usage:

```
typelist<int, float, char>{}.for_each([](auto t)
{
    using type = typename decltype(t)::type;
    // Use `type`
});
```

---

C++20 usage (with minor changes to `typelist`):

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct typelist
{
    template <typename F>
    constexpr void for_each(F&& f)
    {
        // C++17 fold expression over comma operator
        (f.template operator()<Ts>(), ...);
    }
};

typelist<int, float, char>{}.for_each([]<typename T>()
{
    // Use `T`
});
```

I wrote a short article related to this subject: [**"compile-time iteration with C++20 lambdas
"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/cpp20_lambdas_compiletime_for.html).

Comment: I really like this, but i can use c++ 11 at best. Is this working on it or c++17 is required?

Comment: Sadly, this is harder to do in C++11. You need to replace the *fold expression* with an `initializer_list` (see [my talk on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk)) and the generic lambda with a `struct` having a templated `operator()`. The usage syntax will not be as nice. It definitely is possible without recursion, though.

Comment: Ok, thank you. In this case maybe it's better to have a list of std::tuple to store all the types and cycle them?

Comment: Using `std::tuple` doesn't change what I said in the comment above. You still need those things to make this work in C++11, and it's never going to be as nice as C++11/14.

Comment: Well, i guess it's better than nothing. Thank you for the very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

We could look at this in a slightly different way and say that what you perhaps *really* want is a vector (or, I would perhaps prefer to say, list) of things to *do*, and that can be achieved in a very generic way with some of the tools in < functional >.  Let's take a look:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

static void process_int (int i) { std::cout << "process_int " << i << "\n"; }
static void process_string (std::string s) { std::cout << "process_string " << s << "\n"; }
// ...                                            

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::function <void ()>> v;

    v.push_back (std::bind (process_int, 42));
    v.push_back (std::bind (process_string, "Hello world"));

    for (auto f : v)
        f ();                    
}
```

Output:

```
process_int 42
process_string Hello world
```

It could hardly be simpler, could it, and you can adapt it in various clever (or not so clever) ways to suit your particular use-case.  Should be fine in C++11, as the live demo shows.  You can also pass a lambda to `std::bind`.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xAkIDlm6ZyganCSJ).